# What is wrong with this code? (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My code doesn’t seem to work i.e. communication with server.
Can someone please tell me what kind of mistake I have made? Did I oversee something?

P.S – new to AJAX.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

else {
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("mySection").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);

xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<section id="mySection">
<h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
</section>
<button onclick="loadXMLDoc()" type="button">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. What does it say? Look at the Network tab. Do you see the request? Do you see a response? Are they what you are expecting? Add `console.log` statements. Is `onreadystatechange` being called? What values to readyState and status get?

Comment: This seems to function just fine. is **ajax_info.txt** in the same directory? Are you sure you have it uploaded? Keep in mind if you run this locally you could get this error in the console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/*******/Desktop/ajax_info.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Answer (score -2):

Your code is perfectly fine. Just check the url you are passing as the second argument in **xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);**. Most probably the file name you are passing is not correct.

To check, if your code is working fine or not just replace the **ajax_info.txt** url with **https://api.github.com/users/octocat** or any other publicly accessible api url or name of any locally stored file (just make sure to pass correct name next time).

**"communication with server" :** Basically, here you are passing local file name that's why its not communicating with server. To make it communicate to server pass actual url, just like above Github url.